# How to access a Firebase project

Tags: firebase

An app developer has written some code for me that is hosted on Firebase. I want access to the code and so they have apparently given me admin access.

It's a simple question, but I can't figure out how to access the project. I log into the console:

[image]

I see how to "create a project", but I don't know how I can access an existing project. I'm assuming thinking about this whole thing in the wrong way somehow. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "they have apparently given me admin access" Can you clarify what they did? If not, it might be better to ask the people who did this, as they can clarify what exactly they did to give you admin access, and what they expect you to do with it.

Comment: I can't speak to them at the moment, which is why I am trying to figure things out myself if possible. They just said they "added me as an admin". Then I got an email from the project: "Follow this link to reset your project-123456789 password for your my@email.com account. I did this and created a password. Now I don't know where to use it.

Comment: Aha, that second part is important. Can you show the exact email you got in your question? I want to determine whether they added you as an application administrator, or as an administrator on the Firebase project level. I suspect it's the former, but the email would allow us to be certain.

Comment: Hello,

Follow this link to reset your project-123456789 password for your my@email.com account.

https://domain-f9915.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=XoApZcNfdDxP4pBS8...

If you didn’t ask to reset your password, you can ignore this email.

Thanks,

Your project-123456789 team

Comment: The subject line was "Reset your password for project-123456789" and it came from an email address "noreply@domain-f9915.firebaseapp.com"

Comment: I'm not sure why it asked me to reset my password because I've never accessed Firebase before. As you can see I'm trying to piece together what's going on.

Comment: That email is for a user that was added to Firebase Authentication in the project, so not as a collaborator to the Firebase project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically have two types of administrators in an app built on Firebase:

- Project/Firebase administrators who access the project in the Firebase console, and can access the backend view of the services there. This is typically used by the developers on the project, and early administrators. To access the Firebase console, you will sign in with a *Google account* on [console.firebase.google.com](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/).
- Application administrators, who use a custom-built interface to manage typical application operations, such as giving roles to users, upgrading accounts, etc. For this type of functionality, you will sign in to the custom built application with a *Firebase Authentication account*.

The email you got came from Firebase Authentication for an account that was created inside the project. There is no way for this account to be a Firebase administrator or even collaborator on the project, so it was more likely meant as an application administrator. This means that any functionality this allows you to access will have to have been built as part of the app itself, and not in the Firebase console.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. The only instruction that was given to me by the developer  after getting my email was "now you go to the Firebase console". But it seems like this might be incorrect information.

Comment: If it is allowing me to be an application administrator, will that allow me to access / edit the code for app? Or does it depend on how they set things up?

Comment: No. An application administrator is a concept that only exists *inside* the application. But even in the Firebase console the chances that you can find all the code for the application is quite small. You'll probably want to ask the dev for access to the code in a repo on Github or elsewhere for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
updaterequest(messagemap) async {
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("mentor")
    .doc("request")
    .update(messagemap)
    .catchError((e) {
  print(e.toString());
});
```

}

This is a code used to update some value  in your firebase collections. You can use get instead of update to retrieve data from firebase collection. There is also some function like add,remove,set it can be used instead of update command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I can't access anything just from the website? Everything has to happen in a terminal?

Comment: In website you can create collection and documents provide data's in different data types and access them in your code you can also create those collection in your code